# How to get parent custom field from attachment

Tags: soql, attachment

I am able to get standard field of parent object in attachment:

```
SELECT Id, Parent.Name, CreatedBy.Name FROM Attachment
```

But how to get custom field from parent attachment, something like:

```
SELECT Id, Parent.Name, CreatedBy.Name, Parent.Custom_Field__c FROM Attachment
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note: [TypeOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) is an optional clause that can be used in a SELECT statement of a SOQL query when you’re querying data that contains polymorphic relationships but it is not yet documented that whether it will support attachment object or not. TYPEOF is currently available as a Developer Preview as part of the SOQL Polymorphism feature.